# Find item with certain attribute with a certain value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to see if a list item with a certain attribute value does not exist. This code will help me find items with a certain attribute, but how do I modify it to check if there isn't a list item with that attribute set to a certain value? For example, if item with someAttributeName = exist does not exist, then...

```
$(parentElement).find('*[someAttributeName]').each(function(index){
  doSomething(this);  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('*:not([someAttributeName="value"])
```

This will return all elements that don't have an attribute with a specific value. See the [jQuery Not Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should have clarified more and gave my example code in an if statement. I'm trying to check if an attribute value pair does not exist, then run a certain function. Does that make sense?

Comment: actually, that helped me figure it out. `if($('#item [someAttributeName="value"]').length == 0)`

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to be able to help. In the future, the more detail you put in your question, the more likely you'll get the answer you're looking for. :)